# how can I get the list of installed packages of a raspbian system from a mounted system disk?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspbian

I have the SD card from a raspberry buster system, which doesn't boot anymore but is still readable.
How can I get the list of installed packages so that I can check which packages had been installed on that system?

Comment: `$ sudo apt-mark showmanual` will show a list of manually installed packages, but I cannot tell how to do that for something else than the active OS. Maybe a `chroot` can be the way to go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around on the SD card I found that the information files for installed packages are in /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list